# antivirus and firewall software

Tags: firewall, antivirus

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and want to know if I need to install firewall/antivirus software. The "Similar questions" seem to all be outdated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question o explain "outdated" and at the same time indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using and include desktop or server.

Comment: define 'outdated' - most of the 'outdated' bits for antivirus and such are still relevant.  Firewall already ships on the system just use `sudo ufw enable` to enable a basic firewall setup.

Comment: Quite a few questions/answers for choice of antivirus are outdated, most choices of the past no longer work on Linux.  Answers of needing an antivirus/firewall are still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Malware/viruses targeting Linux are pretty rare, to the point that you usually don't need to install an antivirus software. If you really need that extra layer of assurance, you can use ClamAV. `sudo apt install clamav clamtk` should do the trick, and give you a nice GUI for it (ClamTk).